# I'm getting java.io.FileNotFoundException for HTTPS URL

Tags: java, android, file

My code is like that:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=44.400000&lon=26.088492&zoom=18&addressdetails=1");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(1024);
        String tmp;
        while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        reader.close();
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());
```

However i am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException at BufferedReader. The address is correct and any browser displays the json result. I need to get the human readable address from lat and lon, also known as reverse geocoding. I have tried many things but nothing worked, so i will be very thankful if you tell me what i am doing wrong. If it is possible i prefer not to use any external library.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using Retrofit to solve such a simple problem?

Comment: He said that he doesnt prefer 3rd part libs @ZUNJAE. Vladimir you get 403 exception from server. 
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=44.400000&lon=26.088492&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

Comment: i have never used Retrofit, there is no reason, however i wonder why the code doesn't work as expected. It is quite simple as you have said

Comment: @Beyazidy is there a workaround for the problem. Why if i use browser there is no 403 response?

Comment: request method should be `GET` not `POST`

Comment: i have tried with GET too, the same result

Comment: @VladimirMihaylov i found the solution and wrote example code block at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code block and found the solution. You can look to parameters of setRequestProperty method

```
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=44.400000&lon=26.088492&zoom=18&addressdetails=1");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        connection.connect();
        connection.getResponseCode(); //if you want to check response code
        InputStream stream = connection.getErrorStream();
        if (stream == null) {
            stream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, i appreciate your desire to help. I have found the problem and will now post the working code

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem seems to be gone for now as the only thing corrected is addRequestProperty instead of setRequestProperty and the user-agent data but i don't think it is so important. I am not so familiar with add and set requestproperty and don't know exactly what is the difference, but it seems to be important in this case.

```
        URL url = new URL("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=44.400000&lon=26.088492&zoom=18&addressdetails=1");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); //POST or GET no matter
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(1024);
        String tmp;
        while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        reader.close();
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());
```

Thank you all for your answers, problem is solved!